# How to UPDATE a single record using three criteria in WHERE clause of UPDATE command?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Basic 2015 as Frontend and Access Database as Backend. I want to UPDATE a single record in a table on the following three bases:

WHERE

```
Sap_No = TxtSap_No AND

MNT (i. e. Month) = CmbMonth.Text (i. e. ComboBox Text) AND

YR (i.e. Year) = CmbYear.Text (i. e. ComboBox Text)
```

My UPDATE Command is as follows:

Try

```
LvMasterCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE LeaveMaster SET  Sap_No= @Sap_No, From_Date= @From_Date, To_Date= @To_Date, LeaveType= @LeaveType, Days= @Days, LeaveStatus= @LeaveStatus , MNT = @MNT , YR = @YR WHERE Sap_No=  " & CInt(TxtSapID.Text) & " AND MNT=  " & MN & " ;"

LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sap_No", TxtSapID.Text)

LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From_Date", DtpFrom.Value)
LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To_Date", DtpTo.Value)

LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveType", LT)
LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Days", LblDays.Text)

LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MNT", MN)
LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YR", YRR)

LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveStatus", "Y")

LvMasterReader.Close()


LvMasterCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
LvMasterCmd.Parameters.Clear()
Exit Sub
Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

But Is Shows

> NO VALUE GIVEN FOR ONE OR MORE CRITERIA EXPRESSION

What is wrong with this code and How to correct it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your variable for year is `YR` but in `LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YR", YRR)` you are using `YRR`  could your problem be as simple as the variable naming being a typo?

You explained the problem statement as including MN and YR but you have typed YRR.

--Starting with the most obvious problem first.

Comment: and MN called as MNT.

Answer (score 0):

you can not update any column if any value in condition was invalid...so you should be sure that these values exists in database then try this format

```
Try
 LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sap_No", TxtSapID.Text)
 LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From_Date", DtpFrom.Value)
 LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To_Date", DtpTo.Value)
 LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveType", LT)
 LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Days", LblDays.Text)
 LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MNT", MN)
 LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YR", YRR)
 LvMasterCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveStatus", "Y")
 LvMasterCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE LeaveMaster SET Sap_No= @Sap_No, From_Date= @From_Date, To_Date= @To_Date, LeaveType= @LeaveType, Days= @Days, LeaveStatus= @LeaveStatus , MNT = @MNT , YR = @YR WHERE Sap_No = " & CInt(TxtSapID.Text) & " AND MNT = '" & MN & "'"
 LvMasterReader.Close()
 LvMasterCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 LvMasterCmd.Parameters.Clear()
 Exit Sub
 Catch ex As Exception
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```